# Pushing Docker image from gitlab-ci to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, azure-container-registry

I am familiar with docker in docker (dind) but using along with `microsoft/azure-cli` image throw `docker command not found`.

Here is my setup for `gitlab-ci.yml` file. I have created `Service Principal` which is used to authenticate to azure cloud and respective resource group.

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  PASSWORD: *********
  TENANT_ID: *****-************-*************
  APP_ID: *********-*****-*****
  CLIENT_ID: ****************
  ACR_ID: *******************


stages:
  - build
  - deploy

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info

build_staging_image:
  stage: build
  image: microsoft/azure-cli
  script:
    - az login --service-principal --username $APP_ID --password $PASSWORD --tenant $TENANT_ID
    - docker build -t azure-vote:latest ./azure-vote
    - docker tag azure-vote votingtestapp.azurecr.io/azure-vote:latest
    - docker push votingtestapp.azurecr.io/azure-vote:latest



deploy:develop:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - az login --service-principal --username $APP_ID --password $PASSWORD --tenant $TENANT_ID
    - az acr login --name votingTestApp
    - az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role Reader --scope $ACR_ID
    - kubectl apply -f azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml
  only:
    - develop
```

Any way to fix this error. I am just trying to create CI/CD pipeline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `microsoft/azure-cli` docker image does have docker installed and the docker socket is not mounted onto the container. This the `docker` command will fail.

You are using the `microsoft/azure-cli` just to login to the registery. But note that you can also login using `docker login`. Check [Log in to a registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli#log-in-to-a-registry).

Therefore, to solve the issue use a `dind` image and login to azure register using:

```
docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword
```

Comment: gonna try this later, hopefully it gonna work. Thanks!

Comment: What is `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` here username ?