# How do I authenticate using a managed identity from gitlab-ci to push a docker container from gitlab registry to Azure web service?

Tags: azure, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, azure-managed-identity

I have researched the way to push docker images from gitlab container registry to an azure resource: [Pushing Docker image from gitlab-ci to Azure Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324762/pushing-docker-image-from-gitlab-ci-to-azure-container-registry)

I have also found the documentation to create managed identities (both *system-assigned* and *user-assigned*) in the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

I am missing to connect the dots on how I can use
`az login —-identity` in a `gitlab-ci.yml`file to access an *azure app service*. The purpose is to push a *docker* image from *gitlab container registry*.

- How can I do this?
- How do I need to configure the *azure app service* (identity / access control)?
- Are there any security concerns? If yes, is `az login —-service-principal` a more secure way to do this? Or any other authentication procedure? `ssh`?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a GitLab CI Job JWT token to login to Azure from within a CI/CD pipeline without needing to store secrets in a GitLab project. In order to do this, you will also need to configure OpenID Connect (OIDC) for ID federation between GitLab and an Azure service principal. This is recommended by Microsoft for authenticating to Azure from CI/CD services, among other use cases.

**Note:** Using OIDC as described below will only work if you are using gitlab.com or a publicly reachable GitLab instance. This is because Azure needs to connect to the token issuer for the keys to validate the token. If you are self-hosting GitLab and your instance is not publicly accessible, you can choose a different credential type for step 2.

### 1. Create a registered app

First, you will need to register an Application in Azure. You can do this by following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) to register an application and create a service principal.

After doing this, make note of the values for **Application (client) ID** and **Directory (tenant) ID** (found in the application Overview pane). These values will be needed for step 3.

### 2. Add the federated credentials

Once your app is registered, you can add federated credentials to the application's service principal. In the Azure portal, go to **registered apps** -> **your application**. In the sidebar, select **Certificates & secrets**. Under the **Federated credentials** tab, click the "Add credential" button

Use the following parameters for the credential configuration:

**Federated credential sceanrio**: *Other issuer*
**Issuer**: your gitlab URL e.g. `https://gitlab.example.com`
**Subject Identifier**: The value of the `sub` claim to match. For example, to allow jobs on the `main` branch of the `contoso/myproject` project to use this service principal, use `project_path:contoso/myproject:ref_type:branch:ref:main`
**Name**: Any descriptive name for the federated credental (e.g. `contoso-myproject-main`)
**Description**: Optional, a description for the federated credential.
**Audience**: your GitLab URL e.g. `https://gitlab.example.com`

### 3. Authenticate to Azure in your job

After the federated credentials are created, you can leverage the `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` token in your job to authenticate with Azure. In this example, we'll use the Azure CLI (`az login`).

```yaml
azure-cli:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  variables:
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: "YOUR Application Client ID"
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: "YOUR TENANT ID"
  script:
    - az login --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --federated-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
    # now you are logged into Azure and can take other actions using the CLI
    # - az resource list # example
```

- `CI_JOB_JWT_V2`: Predefined variable
- `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`: The Application (Client) ID of the registered application.
- `AZURE_TENANT_ID`: The ID of the Azure Tenant to login to (can be found in the application overview)

Also, don't forget to grant your registered app appropriate permissions for Azure container registry

Comment: very nice input - thanks 
However, it's not exactly login in with a managed identity?

Comment: @aknott ah, I failed to mention this important bit. You can only use managed identities from Azure services running in Azure. Unless your GitLab runner is running on an Azure VM, AKS, or similar Azure service, you cannot use managed identities from GitLab CI. OIDC with federated identity credentials is the closest thing to it, which is what I'm suggesting as an alternative to what you're asking about :-)

Comment: Ok, that explains it! Microsoft "forgot" to mention that in the extensive documentation of the login. And that explains as well, why I cannot even ping the IP address that manged identities is trying to connect to. And yes, my gitlab is not hosted on Azure.

Comment: Gitlab now documents this themselves: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/azure/index.html, with more useful info in the parent doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/).